# What element is the left upper corner of a bookdown in R?

Tags: r, yaml, bookdown

I create a `bookdown` and try to modify the left upper corner. I cannot find the name of this element.

Some authors have a short version of the title:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/

[image]

Some have a logo (I also like to have this)

https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/

[image]

https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/

Some have skipped this features completely

https://bookdown.org/melissaksharp/STROBE_eduexpansion/

[image]

How can this be done? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the config option `toc: before`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#gitbook-style) for `bookdown::gitbook`, e.g.,

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="...">My Awesome Book</a></li>
        <li><img src="..." /></li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really tried to find out from the PANDOC manual as you suggest. And investigated the index source of https://github.com/mca91/EconometricsWithR/blob/master/index.Rmd who seemed to solved it differently. For my solution I also added some css in the `style.css` to center the image https://html-online.com/articles/image-align-center/